# Cannot connect/insert to remote MongoDB (4.0/2.7) C# .NET Framework 4.6.1 (nor 4.6)

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I have tried all the binding settings I could, and I have also tried the "resultset" parameter in the connection string, as per another post.

Basically I have a little mongodb test that works perfect on local machine, but I cannot for the life of me connect from another computer on the same network.
The code is in a small console test app that works locally.
However, as I said, I can see the documents I have successfully added locally.

Firewalls on both machines are OFF.
I've tried all the binding settings I could, and nothing seems to have an effect.
I've tried alternate ports.

I know the server is up and running, I'm looking at it, I can connect and insert when I run the test on the local machine. I just cannot connect and insert remotely. I tried `0.0.0.0`, the server ip itself, combination of the two (bindIp: `0.0.0.0`, `192.168.x.x`) but nothing seems to work.

telnet {my mongo test server} 27017 (or any alternate port), also fails.

I've read as many posts on seemingly related issues as I could, and have tried the suggestions, but I simply cannot get this to work.

UPDATE: I can also ping the server from the would-be client computer.

UPDATE: I'm quite sure it's an OS issue (2008R2), but I honestly can't say with absolute certainty. I've tested from a number of other computers, VM and physical, Windows 7 and 10, and my test app works great. So, I'm just going to reorganize what's doing what and where, and move on.

---

EXCEPTION:

> Unhandled Exception: System.TimeoutException: A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Sele
>   ctors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00
>   .0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "Automatic", Type : "Unknown", State : "Disconnect
>   ed", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "192.168.1.195:27017" }", EndPoint: "192.168.1.195:27017", State: "Disconne
>   cted", Type: "Unknown" }] }.

---

SERVER: (mongodb 4.0, Windows 10, VM --development machine that I have been using for quite some time now)

mongod --config mongod.conf

---

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: c:\thingies
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path:  %MONGO_LOG_PATH%\mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0

#processManagement:

#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

---

CODE: (2.7 driver, vs 2017/.NET 4.6.1, 64bit, stripped down console app --also built and tried with .NET 4.6)

```
IMongoClient _client;
IMongoDatabase _database;
IMongoCollection<ThingyClass> _collection;

_client = new MongoClient("mongodb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017");

_database = _client.GetDatabase("ThingyDB");
_collection = _database.GetCollection<ThingyClass>("Thingies");

ThingyClass thingy = new ThingyClass();

Console.WriteLine("Putting thingy...");

_collection.InsertOne(thingy);
```

Comment: I don't think it is related to the framework version. I tested it under the same conditions. I'm not getting an error. Can you try  bindIp: 0.0.0.0 remove on mongo config file try again.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I removed mongod.conf from the equation and tried launching with --bind_ip_all, --bind_ip 0.0.0.0, several ports. All same results. Local works. Remote doesn't, I'd say it might be my network, but I find it odd that I can drop my test on any other Windows 7 or 10 machine of various flavors and purpose, in several physical locations, and it works. The client/server in question are in the same physical location, but I can also hit it from my remote office over vpn from my Win 10 desktop.

Comment: I think there's something up with my machines, but I don't know what. I also tried to install the 2008 4.0.2 server on the machine I was attempting to test mongo client app from, and that didn't work either. Kept getting the 'entry point/Kernel32' error. Not sure if they are connected to the same root problem. Simply can't get anything mongo to run on those machines. Anyway, I'm going to move on and rearrange things for now so I'll just run on different boxes. No biggie.